# Spring RabbitMQ PooledChannelConnectionFactory, transactional vs non-transaction pool settings

Tags: java, spring, spring-rabbit, rmq

I have a Spring Boot service that needs to listen to messages across multiple RMQ vhosts. So far I only need to consume messages, though in the short future I might need to publish messages to a third vhost. For this reason I've moved towards explicit configuration of the RMQ connection factory - one connection factory per vhost.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#choosing-factory) the PooledChannelConnectionFactory fits my needs. I do not need strict ordering of the messages, correlated publisher confirms, or caching connections to a single vhost. Everything I do with rabbit is take a message and update an entry in the database.

```
@Bean
PooledChannelConnectionFactory pcf() throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    //Set the credentials
    PooledChannelConnectionFactory pcf = new PooledChannelConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    pcf.setPoolConfigurer((pool, tx) -> {
        if (tx) {
            // configure the transactional pool
        }
        else {
            // configure the non-transactional pool
        }
    });
    return pcf;
}
```

What I require assistance with is understanding what the difference between the transactional and non-transactional pool is. My understanding of RMQ and AMQP is that everything is async unless you build RPC semantics ontop of it (reply queues and exchanges). Because of that how can this channel pool have transactional properties?

My current approach is to disable one of the configurations by setting min/max to 0, and set the other to a min/max of 1. I do not expect to have extreme volume through the service, and I expect to be horizontally scaling the application which will scale the capacity to consume messages. Is there anything else I should be considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pools are independent; you won't get any transactional channels as long as you don't use a `RabbitTemplate` with `channelTransacted` set to true, so there is no need to worry about configuring the pool like that.

Transactions can be used, for example, to atomically send a series of messages (all sent or none sent if the transaction is rolled back). Useful if you are synchronizing with some other transaction, such as JDBC.